# How to implement httpContext.session.set with character value? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpcontext

I want to set a character value just like we set string values using `httpContext.session.setString`.

It only shows me 3 functions - `set`, `setInt`, `setString`.
Have already tried `set` and it does not work.

Help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Convert your `char` to a string and use the `SetString` option. Or `Set` takes a `byte[]`, to use it convert your `char` to a byte and store it in the byte array. Or if your `char` happens to be a number, convert it to an `int` and use `SetInt32`. The choice is yours based on your needs. Then reverse the process and call the related `Get`, `GetInt32`, or `GetString` method and convert the value back to your `char`. If you really need to use a `char` then `Get` may be your best option.

Comment: Alright, so you are saying - set it as a string and while using get, convert it to char, right?

Comment: @VarunGupta What's so special about `Char`?

Answer (score 0):

Option # 1 - Use `GetString` and `SetString` to store as string and convert between string and char

```
char myChar = 'Z';
// set char by converting it to a string
HttpContext.Session.SetString(nameof(myChar), myChar.ToString());
// get as string from session
string readValue = HttpContext.Session.GetString(nameof(myChar)) ?? String.Empty;
// check and convert to char
char charFromString = readValue.Length > 0 ? readValue[0] : ' ';
```

Option # 2 - Use `Get` and `Set` and store as byte and convert between char and byte

```
// set char by converting it to a byte[]
HttpContext.Session.Set(nameof(myChar), new byte[] { Convert.ToByte(myChar) });            
// use get to read the byte[] and convert the first byte to a char
// (should be the only byte in the array)
char charFromByte = Convert.ToChar(HttpContext.Session.Get(nameof(myChar))?[0]);
```

Option # 3 - Create extension methods `GetChar` and `SetChar`

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static void SetChar(this ISession session, string key, char value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, value.ToString());
    }

    public static char GetChar(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var value = session.GetString(key);
        return value == null ? default : Convert.ToChar(value);
    }        
}
```

And to use the extension methods from Option # 3...

```
HttpContext.Session.SetChar(nameof(myChar), myChar);
char somechar = HttpContext.Session.GetChar(nameof(myChar));
```